# Just installed mongodb cant connect to server on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I just completed an installation of mongodb in my computer and, after starting and enabling it I keep getting the same error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.23
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2022-11-10T16:25:32.787+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
@(connect):2:6
2022-11-10T16:25:32.788+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2022-11-10T16:25:32.788+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I uninstalled and installed multiple times and tried solutions that worked for other people in similar posts but I can not make it work.

I have a feeling it have something to do with the port it is looking for (27017) but I do not know how to check if that is the problem and, if so, how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you start the mongod service? Is it running?

Comment: Yes it is started and running.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few things to consider:

1. Check if the MongoDB process is running (you can verify using `ps`, `netstat` (check listen port) command in the server.
2. See if your MongoDB service runs locally. That is because by default, the listen address of MongoDB is localhost/loopback.
3. Check if the firewall is running and you have allowed the port.
4. Verify if you are able to use `telnet` to command the port 27017 from the application server.